# Wix - Custom installation directory

Tags: .net, wix, installation, windows-installer, wix-gui

I'm using Wix 3.x and the user should be able to choose the target directory. My Setup.wxs is currently like here: http://pastebin.com/uH1EjbDQ

What is the simplest way to ask the user for a custom target directory? (INSTALLDIR/TARGETDIR?!) I have seen example in which people build there own dialog pages but this isn't really necessary, is it?

Update:

When I add

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR"/>
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

after `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />` but before `</Product>` I get the following error:

`The primary key 'ExitDialog/Finish/EndDialog/Return/1' is duplicated in table 'ControlEvent'.  Please remove one of the entries or rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision. (LGHT0130) - C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\WixUI_Mondo.wxs:44`

Now when I remove `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />` I can build the setup. But the dialog "Choose Setup Type" (Complete, Typical, Custom) is not shown anymore. And another weird thing: Sometimes a dialog pops up, stating it calculates disk space (it has a cancel button), but eventually it never closes by itself. When I close it I can still continue. Is there a way to fix this in a simple manner?

Thanks, Philip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The UIRef element refers to one of the standard user interface sequences provided by WiX:

- WixUI_Mondo
- WixUI_Advanced
- WixUI_FeatureTree
- WixUI_InstallDir
- WixUI_Minimal

You can only use one of these sequences in your installer. Each one of these has a set of dialogs. For information on what dialogs are included in each of these sequences see the [WiX documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/).

The WixUI_Mondo allows the user to specify the installation directory if they choose a Custom install. Only WixUI_Mondo allows the user to choose a typical, custom or complete install.

The simplest way to allow the user to choose the installation directory is to use the WixUI_InstallDir dialog sequence.

SharpDevelop's own installer uses the WixUI_FeatureTree dialog sequence.

So if one of the standard sets of dialogs provided by WiX is not what you want you could look at [customising the dialog sequence](https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html). Creating your own custom dialogs is generally the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

IsWiX supports this feature.  Take a look at:

[IsWiXMerges.wxs](http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56616#1053366)

[IsWiXInstaller.wxs](http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56616#841600)

The trick is that I'm using a Directory named INSTALLLOCATION along with a UIRef of WiXUI_*.   This is what the WiXUI uses similar to the way InstallShield uses INSTALLDIR and Visual Studio uses TARGETDIR.