# How can I add an optional UI to WiX toolset

Tags: user-interface, wix, windows-installer, wix3.6, wix-gui

I have already made a quiet installer (without the need to click any buttons but some progress bar is shown while installation is in progress) for a project deployment. This time I wish to add an optional graphical user interface.

By default, the installer should just run without clicking anything, when a parameter is given, let's say, the `msiexec` parameter: `/qf`, the installer would pop up an interface that can be interacted with.

I've already added the required UI dll to the project reference, but given `msiexec /i C:\Setup.msi /qf`, it doesn't work. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the procedure described in [**this well known Wix tutorial**](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry)?

At its simplest level, this means that you essentially just add this to the Wix source file and you get a **default GUI**:

```xml
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
```

You can also try the other "defaults":

- WixUI_Mondo (normal)
- WixUI_FeatureTree
- WixUI_InstallDir
- WixUI_Advanced

A search turned up [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4699541/129130), and one [talking about extending the default gui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2052914/129130).

Comment: I've read about the WiX tutorial but I do not want to have a default UI. When, let's say, a parameter is given in command line when executing the MSI package, then the UI would popup.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the **WixUI_Minimal.wxs file**:

- [How to build a minimal WiX installer UI without a license page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597025/how-to-build-a-minimal-wix-installer-ui-without-a-license-page)
- [WiX toolset WixUI_Minimal Dialog Set](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_minimal.html)
- [Customised UI's for WiX](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/customised-uis-for-wix.html)

Then use properties to condition the dialogs to show or hide as you launch the MSI via msiexec.exe.